# Access Node-TS app running in Windows server 2019 from any computer

Tags: node.js, windows-server-2019

I've a Node-TS based Opensource ERP [Gauzy](https://gauzy.dev) deployed and running in a Windows server 2019 and I want to allow access and connect a domain to this app so that it can be accessed from anywhere by any number of users. Reason for windows server is this app just doesn't work with HTTPS in Ubuntu, wasted more than two weeks in that.

The problem is I've not found any link/resource mentioning the same.

Because the app runs two servers at the same time, one for the frontend and one for the backend, according to the author, it's better to use two sub-domains of a single domain which I already did.

I can't even access the running server using the server's IP as the domain as in http://ip:3000, it says the server refused to connect so, there's a missing network setting in the server that I don't know about.

Things I tried:

1. Disabling Firewall.
2. Allowing private and public network to the app.
3. Allowing private and public network to the Node. (a solution in some answers)

The solution required: Access Node app from any computer and use a domain instead of the server's IP for it.

Comment: This really requires placing a web server in front of the app, acting as a reverse proxy. They ship [their own server](https://github.com/ever-co/ever-gauzy/wiki/Gauzy-Server) which seems to be for this purpose, but even that doesn't appear to support https, so you would have to put yet another one in front of it. Anyway, despite their claims, this project doesn't look production ready. There is far too much stuff missing, such as documentation. I do not think you will have any more success on Windows than on Linux.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I already use Gauzy-Server for it. And Yes, they miss a lot of documentations and even with direct support from the author by filing two issues, no proper solution was given, I asked two questions on SO and Ubuntu Exchange as well but nothing helped. 
I'm using Windows at least I'm able to run it on windows properly. On Ubuntu, they've not even mentioned what to do or run after installing the debian app. Their URL in the app doesn't update as well but that issue wasn't solved either. It's just that it is still easy to run and understand than ERPNext.